# Unexpected end-of-input:Parse Json using jackson

Tags: json, jackson

I am trying to read db configuration details and I am parsing the json string using jackson mapper and getting exception as Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY.

DatabaseConfiguration is a pojo class with two variables Name and Value
I need to parse this using jackson parser.

> Exception:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected
>   end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: [; line:
>   1, column: 0])
>        at [Source: [; line: 1, column: 3]

JsonString:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "driverclass", 
        "Value": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    }, 
    {
        "Name": "password", 
        "Value": "abc"
    }, 
    {
        "Name": "url", 
        "Value": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
    }, 
    {
        "Name": "username", 
        "Value": "abc"
    }
]
```

also tried json String:

```
 [ { "Name": "jdbc.connection.driver_class", "Value": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" }, { "Name": "password", "Value": "abc" }, { "Name": "url", "Value": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false" }, { "Name": "username", "Value": "abc" } ]
```

code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

public class Parser {

    private static void parseJson(String dbConnectionValues) {

        try {

            List<DatabaseConfiguration> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(dbConnectionValues,
                    TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class));

            for (DatabaseConfiguration l : list) {
                String key = l.getName();
                String value = l.getValue();
                System.out.println("key:" + key + "value:" + value);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = args[0];
        parseJson(jsonString);
    }

}



   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    String name;
    String value;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to replicate your exact exception, but I do see naming convention issues in your java class & json object. You are not following the camel casing, and it will definitely lead to incorrect field mappings & thus will cause different parsing exception than the one you are facing.

I just made these changes to your json string & DBConfig class, and I was able to run the code successfully.

```
class DatabaseConfiguration {

    String name;
    String value;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}


String testJson = "[{\"name\":\"driverclass\",\"value\":\"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\"},{\"name\":\"password\",\"value\":\"abc\"},{\"name\":\"url\",\"value\":\"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false\"},{\"name\":\"username\",\"value\":\"abc\"}]";


[
   {
      "name":"driverclass",
      "value":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   },
   {
      "name":"password",
      "value":"abc"
   },
   {
      "name":"url",
      "value":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
   },
   {
      "name":"username",
      "value":"abc"
   }
]
```

Your command line json input string should look like this, enclosed with double quotes:

```
"[ { \"Name\": \"jdbc.connection.driver_class\", \"Value\": \"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\" }, { \"Name\": \"password\", \"Value\": \"abc\" }, { \"Name\": \"url\", \"Value\": \"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false\" }, { \"Name\": \"username\", \"Value\": \"abc\" } ]"
```

Comment: I cannot change the json string case type. I added @JsonProperty("Name") to my class still it didnt work.however  if I remove the spaces in my json string it works.

Comment: are you saying it works with minified json but not with formatted json ?

Comment: [{"Name":"jdbc.connection.driver_class","Value":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"},{"Name":"password","Value":"abc"}] -this works perfectly fine.

Comment: I am not sure why it doesnt work if i dont remove the spaces  any idea?

Comment: I tried with your json string and it works. Can you try to compare with this [code](https://github.com/amithkumarg/solutions/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oss/shop/Assignment/JsonArrayParse.java) & see what's the difference ?

Comment: thanks, this code works for me too. However I want to read my jsonstring through command line arguments.and when i ran the same code with json inputs i mentioned in the question it doesnt work.

Comment: getting this exception: [
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array (start marker at [Source: (String)"["; line: 1, column: 1])

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you pass as command line arg or hardcoded string, the code should behave correctly in both cases. Can you make sure when you are passing through command line the whole string is enclosed in double quotes, so the jvm takes it as one arument, and doesn't split into multiple args separated by space ?